# Can't find lodash.pull function for Ruby array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, lodash

Is there any utility function which works like [lodash.pull](https://lodash.com/docs#pull) but for Ruby arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the delete method to remove occurrences of a single value:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd']
arr.delete 'b'

# ['a', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Or you can use the - or -= operator to delete an array of values.

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd']
arr -= ['a', 'c']

# ['b', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several equivalent of the `_.pull`, but they work with one value at a time.

You could use

```
[:a, :b, :c, :a, :b].delete(:a) # => can't accept multiple arguments
```

Or you could use

```
[:a, :b, :c, :a, :b].delete_if{|x| [:a, :b].include? x}
```

Or you could use @andrunix approach above by subtracting the array:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd']
arr -= ['a', 'c']
```